# Displaying a description based on code in database

Tags: c#, database, winforms

Displaying a description based on code in database
C#, database, WindowsApplication,

Hi everyone, i have a question how do i input the descriptions columns if i type the number based on my database in code columns, i already retrieve the code from database, but now i also want to display the description when the code shown too.

[Here is the link for show you how is my retrieve the code from database](https://www.dropbox.com/s/it3z0bgnn4nmitv/Pictures.docx)

Here is my code for retrieve the "code" (0001, 0002, and so on)

```
string connectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
OleDbDataReader dReader;
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Code] FROM [Data]", conn);
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
AutoCompleteStringCollection codesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
while (dReader.Read())
{
    string numString = "000" + dReader[0].ToString();
    codesCollection.Add(numString);
}
dReader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add that into your query.

```
"SELECT [Code], [Description] FROM [Data]"
```

and in your while loop, `dReader[1]` will have the value from the description column

```
while (dReader.Read())
{
    string numString = "000" + dReader[0].ToString();
    codesCollection.Add(numString);

    string description = dReader[1].ToString();
    otherCollection.Add(description);
}
```

Comment: i knew [1] is for Description Column in my database. But, what do you mean by "in your while loop, dReader[1] will have the value from the description column"? Do i have to change the "string numString = "000" + dReader[0].ToString();" to "string numString = dReader[1].ToString();"? Sorry, i am new in c# and also in programming.

Comment: it would be a separate statement like i added

Comment: please refer to my comment Sir Jonesy, i comment it with the code also